# Qt Creator Beautifier and different projects

Tags: qt, qt-creator

We would like to associate different kind of styles to different projects. I have been looking for and Qt Creator in its new version (4) has the possibility to autoformat files on saving using Beautifier.

My Question is if there is any way to associate for example a style file to one project to be opened when we open that project.

That file would be in the root folder of the project and would be downloaded automatically from the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the 'Beautifier' options, I see that 'Artistic Style' and 'Uncrustify' has an option to use a file from the project directory as the style file. It's up to you to create these files for each project.

**Update for clangformat:** If you select the "File" option from the "Predefined Styles" list, clang-format should use a file from the project directory. For more info see the description for `-style` argument [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Comment: I have seen what you say and I've tried it. It works thank you. I wonder if there is no way to use clangformat instead of the other two because it is quite faster.

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely missing the file-based option for clang-format, so that different styles based on the opened project or different project versions (clang-format config checked in with sources) was supported.

Comment: @HeyYO Thanks, I totally oversaw the `file` parameter! Works great.